# How to select images from my Desktop in Keynote?

Tags: keynote

In Keynote 6 you can edit images on master slides to serve as Media Placeholders. I've created a theme for our company that has several slides with Media Placeholders configured like this.

Problem is that when someone adds an actual slide and clicks the media button on the placeholder a window pops up which apparently reads someones iPhoto library and only shows those images. Most of the images we use in our presentations are on the company NAS however so storing them in iPhoto isn't really practical.

[image]

How can I add folders to this media browser or make it so that when someone clicks the placeholder button, he can have a default Finder browser so he can select images from any location on his Mac?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but couldn't get it to work over this dialogue. It's kind of weird that you can only use images from Library Files over that button.

The solution is to go to "image in the "Format" band on the right of Keynote. There is another button to "replace" the image. You can choose any file from there...

Hope that helps, since I'm from Germany I don't know the exact denotations in the English version. If you cannot find the right button, just let me know ;)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Wish they would make this an option when placing an image originally, versus just replacing. Thank you.

Comment: More than a year later, and they still have the same annoying behavior!

Answer (score 1):

You can also drag and drop photos from Desktop / Finder into Keynote.